# how to redirect the link to a category in the website

Tags: link-category

Hi Im really new to wordpress and this error is really stressing me out
everytime I click a link in my category sidebar it redirects me to the homepage any idea on how to resolve this problem

[image]

this is my sidebar in my news page

the url it gives is (websitename)/category/announcements/
the link is correct but the page is wrong

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what exactly is going on without more information, but seeing as you're new to Wordpress, it may just be a simple Permalink issue. When on your dashboard, go to Settings > Permalinks, and change this to the "Post Name" option.

If that doesn't work, please provide more information. Is category an actual category, or is it a page? Is announcements a page or a post of a certain category? Anything you can tell us will help.

Comment: hi thanks for answering the permalink is already in the post name option the category and the announcement are both pages actually the links under the category and the links under the archives have the same issue for example if I click the announcement link under the category the url will give me (website name)\category\announcements but the page will show the home page thanks

Comment: So the url is correct, but the page being displayed is your home page? What if you go to a 404 url, such as example.com/category/abcdef. I've noticed that when I have a template related issue, I can go to any url that would normally 404, and it'll just show the home page no matter what. If you have any custom templates in the works, or any plugins that effect templates, check those.

As per usual debugging, if that doesn't work, disable all plugins, visit permalinks (to reset them), and try then.

Comment: hi I already tried to go to a 404 url and it displayed the 404 page not my homepage